# Can a sub-web.xml be deployed in jboss application?

Tags: jboss, glassfish

I am converting a glassfish web application (.war) to be able to deploy it on a jboss (wildfly) server.

The original glassfish .war contains a **sun-web.xml** file. I am simply wondering if I'm required to convert the **sun-web.xml** file before it can be added to the equivalently converted jboss war.

Stated another way, is the **sun-web.xml** file compatible with only glassfish servers, or it is also applicable/compatible with jboss?

Thank-you kindly